# QuickBlox Android SDK 1.2 isn't running anymore on Android API before 14

Tags: android, quickblox

QuickBlox (Android SDK) isn't running anymore on Android API Before 14.

When I try to create a session for QuickBlox using QBAuth.createSession(new QBCallbackImpl() {, it gives this error:

(javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate).

The strange thing that it was running before!

I'm using QuickBlox Android SDK 1.2.4, should I migrate to SDK 2? but it is still Beta!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is a problem when using QuickBlox Android SDK 1.2, highly recommended to use QuickBlox Android SDK 2 (but it still Beta!).

If we still need to use QuickBlox Android SDK 1.2, we can work around that by calling this before creating the session

```
QBSettings.getInstance().setTransferProtocol(TransferProtocol.HTTP);
```

It works like a charm.